# Using strings in functions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Using the embrace operator `{{ }}` is not having the desired effect when I want to use strings inside a `dplyr` function.

For instance, imagine I want to programatically `group_by` variables I find in names of  `data.frame`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

palmerpenguins::penguins %>% 
  select(c(1, 2, 8)) %>% 
  names %>% 
  map(
    function(i)
      penguins %>%
        group_by({{ i }}) %>% 
        tally
  )
```

returns

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"species"`     n
  <chr>       <int>
1 species       344

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"island"`     n
  <chr>      <int>
1 island       344
```

But I want to `group_by` the variable names passed to `map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{{}}` operator is not meant to be used with strings, it's meant for use with symbols. With strings you can either do

```
palmerpenguins::penguins %>% 
  select(c(1, 2, 8)) %>% 
  names %>% 
  map(
    function(i)
      penguins %>%
      group_by(!!rlang::sym(i)) %>% 
      tally
  )
```

or

```
palmerpenguins::penguins %>% 
  select(c(1, 2, 8)) %>% 
  names %>% 
  map(
    function(i)
      penguins %>%
      group_by(.data[[i]]) %>% 
      tally
  )
```

the latter of which is the currently preferred method by the tidyverse authors.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for the `{{}}` operator? I've found this [https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) which isn't much help.

Comment: The `{{}}` operator and related functions are documented on the `?"nse-force"` help page.